# Does udev (/udev) consume storage?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Let's say I install a single partition (root) of linux that's 20GB. When I run 'df' it shows me the root drive that's 20GB, udev, and several tmpfs info. I believe tmpfs is just temporary and from memory, but is udev an actual file system that takes part of that 20GB or is it just temporary as well?

In short, should it be factored into a disk usage report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  It consumes memory, but any disk usage is transient use of swap space that would not persist across a reboot.