# can i use the udev folder to copy my files so i can free up my /dev/sda1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I have the below space utilization can i move some of my files to udev to free up my space ?

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            15432144        8  15432136   1% /dev
tmpfs            3088396      336   3088060   1% /run
/dev/sda1       20608636 19249012    399636  98% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none            15441980        0  15441980   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
```

Comment: Udev is not permanent storage -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/223120/117549

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not! Of what you see there, only `/dev/sda1` represents a real storage device with physical existence. The others are virtual filesystems that the system creates so that various system resources can be accessed as files. The `udev` entry, mounted at `/dev`, contains a representation (as files) of all of your hardware devices and of various virtual devices that the system creates for its own purposes. For example, `/dev/sda1` is your hard drive (strictly, the first partition of the first physical hard disk).

If you try to move files there, *best*-case scenario is that the system doesn't let you. Second best is that you lose the files. Although the system allocates space for the `udev` mount, it's all stored in RAM and gets deleted when the system is shut down. Worst-case, you nuke the system and have to completely start fresh, including repartitioning and reformatting the hard drive.